# Short about reincarnation and a secret handshake

Tags: story-identification, short-film

I saw a short film a few years ago (maybe ~5 but could be more) about a grandmother and her grandson that come up with a secret handshake. Then they're both reincarnated over and over again, accidentally meet up, and start to remember their secret handshake bit by bit as they meet in new lives.

Extra details:

- I think the original grandmother and grandson were of African descent but I'm not certain. I'm pretty sure they were reincarnated as various races throughout time.
- I think in the final scene when they remember the whole handshake and recognized each other, the male was an older (~60) African American and the female was a young (~25) white female.
- The movie was definitely live action, little if any CGI or special effects at all.
- The dialog was in English with, AFAIK, a generic North American accent.
- Probably between 5 and 10 minutes long, no longer than 15.

I'm pretty sure I saw it on YouTube but I can't find it or remember the title. Does this sound familiar to anyone?

Comment: One good source of short sci-fi films on Youtube is [Dust](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC7sDT8jZ76VLV1u__krUutA). I'm not sure how searchable it is, unfortunately, but it's possible your film might be there.

Comment: Was it definitely set in America, or when you say "African American" do you mean "black"?

Comment: @Randal'Thor I already spent some time trying to limit my searches to DUST, no joy. And yes, "black" if that's your terminology preference. I remember the language and accents as "generic American English" so either my memory is filling in the blanks with common defaults or it was US or Canadian.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for [**Next Life**](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2424698/) from 2014.

> A dying woman comes up with a plan to find her grandson in the next life. Or the one after that.

**That plan is a secret handshake.** They're both Caucasian at first, but other than that you remembered it all well; they meet in another life in a futuristic room with one of them being a young white woman and the other an older black man. The film's creator put it online and here it is [and you can find a longer cut [here](https://vimeo.com/81139400)]:

Comment: Amazing! Thank you. I've been trying to find this short for years.